# Create AttributeSet programmatically

Tags: android

I want to create programmatically Preferences from Xml attributes (the xml generated programmatically too)

For example

```
pref=new CheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Seems that would do it but I don't see how to construct the AttributeSet from some arbitrary xml text. Is that possible?

Comment: i never tried that, what about Resources.getXml(int id) ?

Comment: The idea is to generate the source xml "on the fly", just to keep all properties in a single var. If it's not possible I'd go programmaticallyh for all the poperties of the Preference.

Comment: so you need to create a class that implements 
android.util.AttributeSet, its only 22 abstract methods to implement ;)

Comment: :-) I am programming with Qt (C++) and calling java for specific operations. Preferences is one quite fuzzy, you never know how much to put on what side (c++ or java). I tought that defining the properties of a preference with xml woud be relatively clean but I guess I will have to go into more detail.